# How to update a key in dynamodb with boto3?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am new to DynamoDB and am having trouble defining a table. I want to have a table like this:

item_name, create_date, update_date

and I need to query and update the items that have a specific item_name and update_date. So in boto3 I wrote

```
table.update_item(
            Key={
                'item_name': item_name,
                'update_date': 0
            },
            UpdateExpression='SET update_date = :val1',
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':val1': 999999999
            }
        )
```

and I get `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Cannot update attribute update_date. This attribute is part of the key`.

In my table definition, I have `item_name` as hash key and `update_date` as range key. How am I going to fix the definition or code so that

1. The update operation succeeds.
2. I can quickly query the table on both `item_name` and `update_date` attributes?

Answer (score 0):

1)First of all updated_date is part of your primary key means primary key in dynamodb is made of two attribute, Hash(item_name) and Range(updated_date) Primary Key, and you cannot primary key.

2) If you want to update the updated_date property then you should update your table configuration and select item_name only as primary key

Answer (score 0):

Changing a primary key sound like a terrible idea.  If the sort key value is going to change, particularly with a timestamp, you can create a new item `put_item()` with the most current sort key. This use case comes up a lot in example code (e.g. last customer login).